# Display all dates between two given dates in php file

Tags: php

**Input:**  Two dates `(eg, oct 1, 2013 to oct 10, 2013)`

**Output:**  one row for each date through starting date to ending date.

My code is like this:

```
SELECT LoginDatetime,
       LogoutDatetime
FROM attendance
WHERE LoginDatetime BETWEEN $FromDate AND $ToDate
  AND userid = $_SESSION['loginid']
```

Output:

```
Oct 1 2013 9 am & Oct 1 2013 6 pm
Oct 10 2013 9 am & Oct 10 2013 6 pm
```

Means, this gives me only days that the person is present, but I want to display all the dates where he is absent also

1. Oct 1 2013 9 am & Oct 1 2013 6 pm
2. absent.
3. absent
4. ...
5. Oct 10 2013 9 am & Oct 10 2013 6 pm

Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming the 'absent' dates have no entry in your database?

Comment: Would it be possible to print the absent days with php while scrolling through the returned queries?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. If you search this website or use google you will find your solution

Comment: the simplest way that comes to mind is looping through the given days and assigning a value to an array for each date, then spitting out the array.

Comment: Yeah, i tried to loop through all the dates and capture them as an array and display each date in a row.  then for each row, pass the date into a function and fetch dates if match exist else return absent

Comment: somehow, i feel there should be an efficient way to do this...i wanna know is there any way to capture modifying the above query, so it would be simple..Yes, the absent days have no entry in the database

Comment: John Conde..I tried searching everything, bcoz Im very new to development, my search might not be efficient, pls suggest me a link that would help if u already know.  Advance thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
$date0 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y', 'Oct 1, 2013');
$date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y', 'Oct 10, 2013');
$day   = new \DateInterval('P1D');
while ($date0 <= $date1) {
    echo $date0->format('M j, Y'), PHP_EOL;
    $date0->add($day);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Oct 1, 2013
Oct 2, 2013
Oct 3, 2013
Oct 4, 2013
Oct 5, 2013
Oct 6, 2013
Oct 7, 2013
Oct 8, 2013
Oct 9, 2013
Oct 10, 2013
```

You can add further checkings insithe the `while` loop in order to get the desired behaviour:

```
// These could come from the database
$dates    = ['Oct 4, 2013', 'Oct 7, 2013', 'Oct 8, 2013'];
$fromDate = 'Oct 1, 2013';
$toDate   = 'Oct 10, 2013';

// Solution
// Remove comments below in order to always show the start and end dates
//$dates[] = $fromDate;
//$dates[] = $toDate;
$date0 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y', $fromDate);
$date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y', $toDate);
$day   = new \DateInterval('P1D');
while ($date0 <= $date1) {
    $string = $date0->format('M j, Y');
    echo (in_array($string, $dates) ? $string : 'Absent'), PHP_EOL;
    $date0->add($day);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Absent
Absent
Absent
Oct 4, 2013
Absent
Absent
Oct 7, 2013
Oct 8, 2013
Absent
Absent
```

**EDIT for PHP < 5.3**

Basic example:

```
$date0 = new DateTime('Oct 1, 2013');
$date1 = new DateTime('Oct 10, 2013');
while ($date0 <= $date1) {
    echo $date0->format('M j, Y'), PHP_EOL;
    $date0->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Advanced example:

```
// These could come from the database
$dates    = ['Oct 4, 2013', 'Oct 7, 2013', 'Oct 8, 2013'];
$fromDate = 'Oct 1, 2013';
$toDate   = 'Oct 10, 2013';

// Solution
// Remove comments below in order to always show the start and end dates
//$dates[] = $fromDate;
//$dates[] = $toDate;
$date0 = new DateTime($fromDate);
$date1 = new DateTime($toDate);
while ($date0 <= $date1) {
    $string = $date0->format('M j, Y');
    echo (in_array($string, $dates) ? $string : 'Absent'), PHP_EOL;
    $date0->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Comment: Apology for not mentioning, am using php 5.2.6

Comment: @user1808995 Done! That should work with PHP < 5.3

Comment: @jackflash..Thanks a lot..It cut my code to almost half n easy